# Flutter How do add Text Field and Radio button in row?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, radio-button, row, textfield

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Material(
              elevation: 30.0,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              child: SizedBox(  
                width: 300,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: heightcon,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Height',

                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                   
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                       
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        width: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (heightval) {
                    print('First text field: $heightval');
                    globals.heightvalue = double.parse(heightval);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: SizedBox(
                      child: Radio(
                    value: 1,
                    groupValue: 1,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  )),
                ),
               
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                
                SizedBox(
                    child: Flexible(
                  child: Text("Radio 1"),
                )),
                Flexible(
                  child: SizedBox(
                      child: Radio(
                    value: 1,
                    groupValue: 1,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  )),
                ),
                
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                
                SizedBox(
                    child: Flexible(
                  child: Text("Radio 1"),
                ))

               
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

The error show like thid:

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#c7c48 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
lib\main.dart:25
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: Please show us your code! The error comes from what the error message says, your row does not know how big it should be! You can put it within a `SizedBox` and give it a size in pixels, or you can see if surrounding your Row with an `Expanded` widget helps

Comment: I just edit this question description adding my code.

Comment: Thank you h8moss I have fix my problem by your  kind answer

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Text("gender"),
                        Radio(
                            value: "male",
                            groupValue: 1,
                            onChanged: (onChanged) {})
                      ],
                    ),
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69232749/edit) your answer to add explanations.

Answer (score 2):

you can check the pic and code for reference.  You can use textfield instead of Text. and yes, when u use textfield wrap it with Expanded.

[image]

```
Row(
        children: [
          const Text('Gender:  '),
          Radio(
            value: 0,
            groupValue: _radioVal,
            onChanged: (int? value) {
              if (value != null) {
                setState(() {
                  _radioVal = value;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
          const Text('Male '),
          Radio(
            value: 1,
            groupValue: _radioVal,
            onChanged: (int? value) {
              if (value != null) {
                setState(() {
                  _radioVal = value;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
          const Text('Female '),
        ],
      ),
```